# Android: 2 Different Notifications with different IDs and texts shows the same text

Tags: android, notifications

As mentioned I am not able to successfully show different messages in my notifications when the devices receives 2 or more notifications. I have tried some of the solutions which I tried but they didnt work. My code to create notification is as below:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Intent showMessageIntent = new Intent(context, AdminMessageActivity.class);
showMessageIntent.putExtra(WorkspaceConstants.ADMIN_MESSAGE_KEY, message);
showMessageIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

int Id = new Random().nextInt();
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, showMessageIntent, 0);
String messageShort = (message.length() > 25) ? message.substring(0, 25) + "..." : message; 

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
.setContentTitle(context.getText(R.string.admin_message))
.setContentText(messageShort)
.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
.setAutoCancel(true);

mNotificationManager.notify(Id, mBuilder.build());
```

I extract the message content with the below code:

```
if(getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null){ 
    mMessageContent = getIntent().getExtras().getString(ADMIN_MESSAGE_KEY); 
} 

mMessage.setText(mMessageContent);
```

---

No exception and no crash in the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show 2 notifications at a time, you should call setData on showMessageIntent with to different values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only changing the extras of an `Intent` passed to `PendingIndent`, then by default it will reuse the initial `Intent` and not update the extras - pass in [PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) as the final parameter to `PendingIntent.getActivity` to ensure that your extras are updated.

Comment: Won't that remove the earlier content text and replace it with the new one so that the user ends up missing the earlier message?